# Send Sms and Mms to users with my company numbers

Tags: python-3.x, django, twilio, sms, mms

Is it possible to utilize a third-party API in Python for sending both MMS and SMS messages? I'm looking to avoid sending SMS messages using the purchase numbers provided by the third-party platform. Instead, I intend to send SMS and MMS using my personal phone numbers or a list of numbers that I can add to the platform.

I've attempted to send messages using Python with Twilio or Click Send, but it seems they only allow sending messages from the numbers they provide on their platforms. What I'm aiming for is to send MMS from my company's specific number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid this is not possible as it would potentially allow a flood of scam and fraud when one could send SMS from numbers that are not managed by Twilio.